# Kubernetes Environment Setup on VirtualBox to learn CI/CD Pipeline (DevSecOps)

Tags: virtualbox, home-networking, home-server, kubernetes, cluster

I am just planning to learn K8s. I am interested in learning about its interconnected technologies, such as the CI/CD pipeline and devsecops. I know all of them are broad topics. But I believe the right setup will help me learn all of them simultaneously.

As far as I know, there are three main environments from development to production: development, staging, and production. Maybe there can be additional setups for manual software testing, etc. And also the learning environment that Kubernetes mentioned in [documents](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/).

The resources I have to learn this are my personal laptop and VirtualBox. So what I want to try is to create virtualboxes for different environments and try CI/CD pipeline (devsecops) setups by allowing virtualboxes to talk to each other. But as I saw different setup suggestions for the learning environment, I am not quite sure how to achieve this. And also, Kubernetes mentions that for production environments managed by a single admin, use Kubeadm for deployment. Then what would be the solution for handing over some parts of management to others?

These questions might be silly because I am just getting started. Anyway, what would be the best setup to learn these skills locally using VirtualBox or in any other means?

Comment: The questions aren't "silly" but being "questions", plural, is a problem in itself and the lack of focus even worse. Please start here: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am sure it is covering different areas at once however everything is connected to one question *How to setup kubernetes on VirtualBox to learn CI/CD Pipeline (DevSecOps)?* Additional questions on kubeadm and learning environment is also connected to this main question. May be those additional questions can be considered as something that more explains the problem... I am not sure how to divide these questions or make it more focused. If you have any idea let me know I'll try to adjust. Anyway, Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Your question is opinion-based on top of that. That's also not allowed here, no matter how you split.